# Excesive Linux Latency

Tags: linux

Do you think that a latency of 50 msec are normal in Linux System?

I have a program with many threads, one thread is controlling the movement of an object with a motor and photocells.

I have made many thing to get minimun latency, but always get 50 msec that cause a position error in the object.

Things I did:
- nice function to -20
- Thread priority of photeocell control thread: SCHED FIFO, 99
- Kernel configuration: CONFING_PREEMPT=y
- mlockall (MCL_CURRENT | MCL_FUTURE);

Many times, I lose 50 msec waiting for a photocell. I think that the problema is not another of
my thread, but process in the kernel.

Is posible reduced this latency? Is posible to know who is getting this 50 msec extra?

The thread that is controlling photocells make many "read" functions. Can this generate problems?

/**********************/

At now the situation is:
There is only one thread running an infinite empty loop, only looking for time at start od the loop an at the end of the loop.
No acces to disk, no acces to GPIO, no serial ports, nothing.
The loop spend 50 milisecond many of the times.

I have not set cpuaffinity, my processor has only one nucleus.

Comment: A quick question - have you set a cpuaffinity? From where you read from (disk? I/O controller? tmpfs?)?

Comment: How does the photocell signal reach the program? I mean, are there GPIOs, serial ports, dedicated hardware?

Comment: Maybe what you are seeing is not actually latency, but the _granularity_ of the clock source.

Comment: @rodrigo: Linux has way better clock granularity than 50ms. Try microseconds, if not nano (depends on hardware). My guess would be that these (unknown, obscure) photo sensors simply take that long to send data via whatever means they use (USB? Wifi? Selfmade I/O board?). The mention of "many read functions [sic]" may suggest polling all the time on nonblocking descriptors, which of course may give some delay too, if there's a few of them... Too many unknowns.

Comment: Need **much** more info. How many sensors are being read, and how often (code!)? Is a readiness notification (select/poll) mechanism being used or are they all polled by hand? How does the data get into the computer (e.g. buggy custom driver?), what hardware is that computer (15-20 year old CPU?) etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have been making test in my program.
This is the code in the main function, before the program star the threads, that cause de 50 mseg latency:

```
struct sched_param lsPrio;

lsPrio.sched_priority = 1;
if (sched_setscheduler (0, SCHED_FIFO, &lsPrio) != 0)
    printf ("FALLO sched_set\n");
```

if I comment this lines the latency is reduced about 1 mseg.

Why this lines cause latency?

Comment: If this thread performs work, it will of course cause latency in other threads, that is what you're asking for. You are telling the kernel to schedule this thread until it is done, and not preempt it with any normal thread. But this is not the original problem, is it?